# How to move elements sideways in html

Tags: html

Hellow i have a question about elements moving sideways.
I have pictures on my webpage and am moving them up and down, left and right but cannot move them to the side. I am using jquery as my script. Do you have any options how to move a picture sideways? 
Thank you wery much for your help.

Comment: post ur code in jsfiddle & share us the link

Comment: This is possible right now [link](http://jsfiddle.net/6qn9pyux/) sample but i need to move it parallel not just left and right or up and down and thank you very much

Comment: What do you mean by 'I need to move it parallel not just left and right...'? Because your demo seems to solve the problem asked in your question.

Comment: no sorry the demo moves just right, left, down and up but I need it to move right and down together, sideways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer
you can put two properties into the function
animate( top: '+=100', left: '+=100'}, 1000);
this makes it move parallel.
Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery .animate function

### scripts :

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#reset').hide();
    $('#move').click(function() {
        $('#left').animate({
        'marginLeft' : "-=100%", //moves left
        'marginTop' : "+=100%" //moves left
        });
        $('#right').animate({
        'marginRight' : "-=100%", //moves right
        'marginTop' : "+=100%" //moves left
        });
        $('#move').hide();
        $('#reset').show();
    });

    $('#reset').click(function() {
        $('#left').animate({
        'marginLeft' : "+=100%", //moves left
        'marginTop' : "-=100%" //moves left
        });
        $('#right').animate({
        'marginRight' : "+=100%", //moves right
        'marginTop' : "-=100%" //moves left
        });
        $('#reset').hide(); 
        $('#move').show();
    });


})
```

### styles :

```
.main-div{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.left-div {
    background:green;
    width:50%;
    float:left;

}
.right-div {
    background:blue;
    width:50%;
    float:right;
}
```

### html body

```
<div class="main-div">
<div align="center"> 
    <button id="move">Move</button>
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
<div id="left" align="center" class="left-div">text and image left<br><img src="http://webnevisan.ir/templates/beez_20/images/logo.png"></div>
<div id="right" align="center" class="right-div">text and image right<br><img src="http://webnevisan.ir/templates/beez_20/images/logo.png"></div>
```

I have edited the code after your comments : 
here is demo with move down and sideways
look at this [**demo link**](http://jsfiddle.net/6qn9pyux/4/)

Comment: Thank you very much but i am already moving my images up and down and left and right but am needing to move them sideways, parallel

Comment: tnx but this is transformation, I dont need transformations i just need to move them :) thank you

Comment: it means you need to move your boxes sideway relative to scroll bar movements ?

Comment: Sorry i dont know what you mean but to be a little more precise down and right together is what i mean tnx for the response

Comment: here id demo with move down and left : [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6qn9pyux/5/)

Comment: @Mesni please accept my answer if your problem solved by my answer.